# iPhone Variable between two views

Tags: iphone, xcode, variables, view

I hope you can help me.

I need a variable, which when I click on any button on View1 (View 1 have 6 Buttons) the Variable should have any value e.g. 1-6. Then in view two I will check the value of the Variable.

Comment: for that you need to declare a global variable in view2 and when you press the button in view1 you'll have to create an instance of view2 and fill the variable with your desired value. this how you can have the value of variable in view2.

Comment: OK thanks have you an example for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your view2.h class should look like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ForgotPasswordViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strName;

@end
```

your view2.m class should look like this

```
#import "ForgotPasswordViewController.h"

@interface ForgotPasswordViewController ()

@end

@implementation ForgotPasswordViewController

@synthesize strName;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Init
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - View LifeCycle
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSLog(@"the value of name is %@",strName);
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Memory Mgmt
-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

in your your view1.m class should should be like

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ForgotPasswordViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - View LifeCycle
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    ForgotPasswordViewController *vcForgotPasswordViewController = [[ForgotPasswordViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ForgotPasswordViewController" bundle:nil];
    vcForgotPasswordViewController.strName = @"Dhaval";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcForgotPasswordViewController animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Memory Mgmt
-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

hope you got it else you can ask me for any help thanks :)